# how to turn this html output into a json builder one RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this problem on turning a html output into a json. I know how to do nested jBUILDER and `has_many` but this one has different I have to get the `user.name` through the `friend_id` since I did a `has_many :through associations`

## user associations

```
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user, dependent: :destroy
```

## friendship associations

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

this line

```
<%=h friendship.friend.name %> shows the name of the user is befriended
 while this line
<% for user in @user.inverse_friends %> show the name the ofthe user the inverse of of friendships
   <li><%=h user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

I use this site http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true as a reference now all i need is to make a jbuilder queryside the users show.json.builder file

**show.json.builder**

```
json.extract! @user, :id, :name

json.projects @user.projects, :id, :name, :descriptions, :startDate, :dueDate, :created_at, :updated_at, :user_id, :project_confirm

json.friendships @user.friendships,:user_id, :friend_id

json.inverse_friendships @user.inverse_friendships, :user_id, :friend_id
```

here is my repo https://github.com/caryamiel/OcolworksTestDev